# Selecting first empty row with specific columns for each sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way that I can possibly make the function change to a specific column for each `sheet` in the `ActiveWorkbook`I tried various versions but can't seem to get it right.

```
Sub resetFilters()

Dim sht As Worksheet

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'On Error Resume Next
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

  End If

Range("A3:T3").ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call GetLastRow


Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
Debug.Print "Error number: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description


End Sub
Private Function SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnH(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, Optional ByVal fromColumn As Long = 8) As Long

    SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnH = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, fromColumn).End(xlUp).Row

End Function

Private Sub GetLastRow()
Dim selectLastRow As Long

selectLastRow = SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnH(ActiveSheet, 8)
 Cells(selectLastRow, 8).Offset(1, 0).Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: You should pretty much never use `.Select` etc in your VBA code as it's pretty much unnecessary.  What are you trying to achieve, specifically?  Also, what exactly is the problem you're seeing - "it's not working right" isn't very descriptive of your issue.

Comment: @Dave I need it to set the `selection` for the first empty cell so that is ready for data entry. How will this be possible without `select`? Also, I need some way to change the column based on the sheet that the user is currently in basically in each sheet there is a table that has almost the same headers and would like to keep the select first empty row the same. The column header will be Style, i don't know if i can pass in the column header as references in the function to retrieve the same result on all `sheets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worksheet is an object and can't be passed as an argument ByVal. It must be ByRef, which is the default and can therefore be omitted. Note also that Sheet is a word reserved for VBA's use. In most cases VBA will be able to determine your intention and allow you to use its vocabulary the way you wish, but for you, when faced with the task of trouble shooting, it is a hell of a job to determine in each case whether Sheet means VBA's sheet or your own sheet. Select any word in your code and press F1 to let VBA show you the meaning it attaches to it and how to use it.

Other than that, note that your function returns the last used row. The first empty one is the next one after that. So, I would write that function somewhat like this:-

```
Private Function FirstEmptyRow(Ws As Worksheet, _
                               Optional ByVal Clm As Long = 1) As Long
    With Ws
        FirstEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Clm).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
End Function
```

Observe that I changed the default for the optional column to 1. The default should be both the most logical choice and the one most commonly used. In the case of the last row that is the first column, column A.

Here is an alternative based on your comment (which I couldn't fully understand). This code looks for the word "Style" in `Rows(3)` of the `ActiveSheet` and returns the next blank row in the column where "Style" was found.

```
Private Function FirstEmptyRow() As Long
    ' 9 Apr 2017

    Dim Clm As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
        Clm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Style", .Rows(3), 0)
        FirstEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Clm).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
ErrHandler:
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

If the word "Style" isn't found an error will occur and the execution will jump to the Label `ErrHandler:` which does nothing. You might want to let it handle the situation in some way. As the function stands the row number it returns will be zero which will cause an error if you try to address that row.

Comment: I need some way to change the column based on the sheet that the user is currently in. Basically there 4 sheets in a workbook that has a table that has almost the same headers and would like to keep the select first empty row on the same column header and there 3 others sheets with charts. The column header will be Style, i don't know if i can pass in the column header as references in the function to retrieve the same result on all sheets or need like a variable to check what is the `ActiveSheet` to pass then the variable in the column of the function to get the right column.

Comment: Yes, you could pass the column caption "Style" as a parameter to the function. I have modified my suggested code above based on the presumption that the caption would always be "Style".

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand why lose all the arguments in `Private Function FirstEmptyRow(Ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal Clm As Long = 1) As Long`?? Will all this not help the function be more good?

Comment: No. It will be different. You said that you want Clm to be different depending upon which sheet the user looks at when he triggers the code. That is the `ActiveSheet` and it is better to say so outright in the sub. Passing it as an argument will only confuse the reader. Same for the Clm which depends upon the `ActiveSheet`. Everything becomes different if you need to read from another sheet. In that case it may be better to specify it in the calling procedure. This is the part of your project I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this function:

```
Private Function SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnWithGivenHeader(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, Optional ByVal header As String = "Style") As Long
    Dim col As Variant
    With sheet
        col = Application.Match(header, .Rows(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(col) Then
            .Activate '<--| you must select a sheet to activate a cell of it
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

and exploit it in your main code as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False '<--| this to prevent sheet activating slow down the code (and annoy you)
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnWithGivenHeader sht , "Style" '<--| you can omit the 2nd parameter and it'll be assumed the default column header
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True '<--| get default behavior back in place
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the desired column number to the function.  `Optional ByVal fromColumn As Long = 8` means that column 8 (column H) is the default column if no column number is passed when the function is called.  But passing a column number will override that default.

So in this line, passing the 8 is actually not required, although probably good for clarity, and could be written like so with the same result (returning the last row for column H):

```
selectLastRow = SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnH(ActiveSheet)
```

To change the column number to 2 (column B) for example, you would change the line like so:

```
selectLastRow = SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumnH(ActiveSheet, 2)
```

I would also recommend that you genericize the name of the function to `SelectFirstEmptyRowInColumn` so to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will help you.

Sub FindFirstEmptyRow()

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

End Sub
☺ ☺